# Event is not binding while creating dynamic controls

Tags: reactjs

When I add an event using the first code snippet, the event is firing. But when i do the same thing with a variable, the event is not firing/binding. can any one help me?

```
var ProductTable = React.createClass({
  ChangeSearch : function(event){console.log("Text changed");},
  render: function() {
      return (<input type="text"onChange= {this.ChangeSearch} />);   
  } 
});
```

same code with variable:

```
var ProductTable = React.createClass({
  var headerFilters =[];
  ChangeSearch : function(event){console.log("Text changed");},

  render: function() {
      headerFilters.push(<th><input type="text" onChange={this.ChangeSearch} /></th>);      
      return ({headerFilters});   
  } 
});
```

First one and the second one are looping through and adding the text boxes. With the variable only i will be able to generalize the code. I have removed the looping from the first code snippet to reduce the complexity.

Comment: show full code please

Comment: you do realize that your second example code is not valid (the declaration of `headerFilters`)?

Comment: Your code is invalid. Not allowed to render a array of elements, must render a component like `<div>{headFilters}</div>`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to render list of input elements its better to create simple element and map over it in Parent. Read react documentation about [dynamic children](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children)

[jssfidle:](https://jsfiddle.net/s4n3446q/1/)

code sample:

```
var InputTextElement = React.createClass({
    changeHandler: function(event) {
        console.log('text.changed' + event.target.value)
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <input type="text" name={this.props.name} onChange={this.changeHandler} />
        )
    }
})

var ProductTable = React.createClass({

render: function() {
    var headerFilters =[{id: 1, name: "test"}, {id:2, name: "another"}];

    return (
        <div>
        {  headerFilters.map(function(data) {
            return  <InputTextElement key={data.id} name={data.name} />;
        })}
        </div>
    );
}
});
setTimeout(function() {
    ReactDOM.render( <ProductTable />
    , document.getElementById('element'))
} ,700);
```

working like a charm.

Comment: i didn't find issue while showing the text box. I am facing issue while binding the events with the text box